# error message when trying to connect to Sybase using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using ssis of sql 2008 trying to connect to sybase 12 using sybase 15.2 driver, i even tried sybase 12 driver and got same error

error message

```
[ZZZZZ]
[Message Class: 16]
[Message State: 5]
[Transaction State: 1]
[Server Name: PHXPROD]
[Native Code: 2812]
[ASEOLEDB]Stored procedure 'sp_oledb_datatype_info' not found. 
Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output). (ASEOLEDB)
```

attached images showing that i am able to connect but soon after connecting i get the error message

Step 1[image: Connect to Sybase successfully]

Step 2 [image: error message as soon as i click next]

Error message when i used ADO.NET    [image: Ado.net to connect to sybase]

Comment: Did you try the latest ASE OLE DB Provider or Sybase ADO.NET provider? To me, it seems the provider supports MS SQL 2005, but doesn't not fully support SQL Server 2008.

Comment: yeah i tried ADO.net and it gave different errors,

Comment: If you post the error with ADO.net probably it can help to understand better the problem

Comment: i edited the same post to add the error message of ADO.NET

Answer (score 1):

Look like you have to investigate more about this problem and by reading in the [SyBooks Online](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00729_1500/html/errMessageAdvRes/CHDBGEGI.htm) it say:

If `error 2812` occurs on **system stored procedures** (as your case **sp_oledb_tables** and **sp_oledb_datatype_info**) it may be resolved by running the **installmaster** script, which installs all system procedures and initializes various other Adaptive Server structures.

**How to run the installmaster script?**

Using `isql`, run the new installmaster script included with this release by entering:

```
isql -Usa -P<sa password> -S<server name> -n -i$SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE/scripts/installmaster 
-o<output file>
```

Reference: [Running the installmaster script](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.aselxqig/html/aselxqig/aselxqig14.htm)

Hope it help you

Comment: i cant find the "scripts" folder in the $SYBASE/$SYBASE_ASE folder, which sybase version are you using

Comment: I use 15 but you are using 12 so up the kind also of the operating system used (win or linux). [Check here all the info for version 12](http://www.sybaseteam.com/post-installation-scripts-tasks-for-adaptive-server-enterprise-t-99.html)